# Feedback on Mono rails

Tags: asp.net, castle-monorail

Has anybody tried Mono rails from Caste project . Unfortunately the client wants to develop in .nET v2.0 and not 3.5 , and I was looking for some MVC framework in .NET 2.0 .

Comment: Why don't you try and persuade them of the business benefits of using .NET 3.5?

Comment: I have already tried that , but for some unknown reason they just want to continue with .NET 2.0  .

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290088/asp-net-mvc-vs-castle-monorail

Comment: "for some unknown reason" I encountered this in a mission, the reason was we don't have vs2008 licences.

Barring newtonsoft json dependency in last MonoRail version (which should be replaceable without compilation by implementing an interface), I think even the last version would work ok with .net 2.0

Answer (score 3):

[Lots of people have successfully used MonoRail](http://forum.castleproject.org/viewforum.php?f=6) for several years. It's a great framework, and if you later want to migrate to ASP.NET MVC it's no big deal.

Unfortunately you'll have to use [RC3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/castleproject/files/Castle%20Project/Release%20Candidate%203/Castle-net-2.0-release-2007-9-20.zip/download) (which is over 2 years old now) to get .NET 2.0 support, as the latest trunk versions only support .NET 3.5.

If you really want to go with ASP.NET MVC you might want to try [this hack](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx) to make it work on .NET 2.0.

Comment: The 3.5 only thing is rather new. Any checkout of a revision from a few months ago will be MUCH better than the old RC, and still work flawlessly on 3.5.

Actually, I'm pretty sure that the trunk will also work on .NET 2.0 with SP2

Comment: @ken: lots of projects in the trunk reference System.Core, e.g. http://bit.ly/6BHuZx

Comment: not in the build script:

http://fisheye2.atlassian.com/browse/castleproject/MonoRail/trunk/src/Castle.MonoRail.Framework/default.build?r=6699

However I'm not sure it's still the same for MR core deps

Answer (score 0):

Try [ASP.NET MVC over ASP.NET 2.0](http://aspnetmvc20.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the link Alon , I will check that out .